# Android: Class 'MainActivity2' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>'

Tags: java, android

I am getting Two Errors:
First On the Class

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements   AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
```

> "Android: Class 'MainActivity2' must either be declared abstract or
>   implement abstract method 'onNothingSelected(AdapterView'  in
>   '"OnItemSelectedListener'"

```
The Second one is on the setOnClickListener(this);

        //Adding listener to button
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }
```

Error: In View cannot be applied

Code from MainActivity2.java

```
//Class for our main activity with OnClickListener
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private WebView webView;
    private EditText trucksID;
    private EditText tripReportNumber;
    public EditText enteredDate;
    private EditText emptyMilage;
    private EditText loadedMilage;
    private Button buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
    private TextView estMilage;
    public String startState;
    public String startTerminal;
    public String endState;
    public String endTerminal;

    Spinner s1,s2,s3,s4;
    public String sp1t;
    //Declaring views
    //This is our root url
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "http:...wp-content/php/";
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        s3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        s4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        s3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                               long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sp1 = String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
        startState = sp1;
        //The spinners for State and Each Start Terminal broken down by State Code
        if (sp1.contentEquals("AL")) {
            List<String> myArrayList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ALTerminalCodes));

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myArrayList);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            startTerminal = String.valueOf(s2.getSelectedItem());
        }
        if (sp1.contentEquals("AZ")) {
            List<String> myArrayList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.AZTerminalCodes));
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myArrayList);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            startTerminal = String.valueOf(s2.getSelectedItem());
        }


// This is the Code for the Third Spinner State / End Terminal coding and selection

        String sp3 = String.valueOf(s3.getSelectedItem());
        endState = sp3;
        //The spinners for State and Each Start Terminal broken down by State Code
        if (sp3.contentEquals("AL")) {
            List<String> myArrayList2 = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ALTerminalCodes));
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myArrayList2);
            dataAdapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter4.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s4.setAdapter(dataAdapter4);
            endTerminal = String.valueOf(s4.getSelectedItem());
        }
        if (sp3.contentEquals("AZ")) {
            List<String> myArrayList2 = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.AZTerminalCodes));
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myArrayList2);
            dataAdapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter4.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s4.setAdapter(dataAdapter4);
            endTerminal = String.valueOf(s4.getSelectedItem());
        }

        //Initializing Views
        trucksID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.trucksID);
        tripReportNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tripReportNumber);
        enteredDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enteredDate);
        emptyMilage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emptyMilage);
        loadedMilage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loadedMilage);
        estMilage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.estMilage);

        //Reset Button for Form
        Button reset= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnclear);

        assert reset != null;
        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                trucksID.setText("");
                tripReportNumber.setText("");
                enteredDate.setText("");
                emptyMilage.setText("");
                loadedMilage.setText("");
                estMilage.setText("");

            }
        });

        //Adding listener to button
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.openWebsite:
                Intent website = new Intent(this, ourWebsite.class);
                this.startActivity(website);
                return true;

            case R.id.about_us:
                Intent about = new Intent(this, aboutUs.class);
                this.startActivity(about);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void insertUser() {
        //Here we will handle the http request to insert user to mysql db
        //Creating a RestAdapter
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL) //Setting the Root URL
                .build(); //Finally building the adapter

        //Creating object for our interface
        RegisterAPITest api = adapter.create(RegisterAPITest.class);

        //Defining the method insertuser of our interface

        int value1 = Integer.parseInt(emptyMilage.getText().toString());
        int value2 = Integer.parseInt(loadedMilage.getText().toString());
        int estMilage = value2 + value1;

        api.insertUser(
                //Passing the values by getting it from editTexts
                trucksID.getText().toString(),
                tripReportNumber.getText().toString(),
                enteredDate.getText().toString(),
                emptyMilage.getText().toString(),
                loadedMilage.getText().toString(),

                //   String emptyLocation = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),

                //can take this out below
                Integer.toString(estMilage),
                // Addign in Locaiton Spinners and assigning to DB
                startState,
                startTerminal,
                endState,
                endTerminal,

                //Creating an anonymous callback
                new Callback<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                        //On success we will read the server's output using bufferedreader
                        //Creating a bufferedreader object
                        BufferedReader reader = null;

                        //An string to store output from the server
                        String output = "";

                        try {
                            //Initializing buffered reader
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));

                            //Reading the output in the string
                            output = reader.readLine();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //Displaying the output as a toast
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        //If any error occured displaying the error as toast
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    //Overriding onclick method
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Calling insertUser on button click
        insertUser();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.johncbell.atrixtrucking/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.johncbell.atrixtrucking/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: I keep looking and this is what was out there, but when I go to the activity, it always fails. "public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {"    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.connect()' on a null object reference at com.johncbell.atrixtrucking.MainActivity2.onStart(MainActivity2.java:931)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 1 is almost pretty clear.. the message asking you to implement/override the 
method `onNothingSelected`

Comment: Yes, i think you mean : "public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {"   Sorry I am very new to Android

Comment: Well I do not know:  After putting like you asked, the logcat, is throwing: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.connect()' on a null object reference at com.johncbell.atrixtrucking.MainActivity2.onStart(MainActivity2.java:932)at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006) ...